# How to insert custom date into table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is some values from a specific column in SQL Server:

```
1899-12-30 00:00:00.0000000
1899-12-30 00:00:00.0000000
2022-03-01 00:00:00.0000000
2022-03-01 00:00:00.0000000
```

Column type is `datetime2(7)`

What is the correct way of creating an insert statement to insert a specific date?

Is this method okay?:

`insert into table1 (date) values ('2020/01/31')`

Is this acceptable? Or should it be:

`insert into table1 (date) values ('2020/01/31 00:00:00.0000000')`?

Using SQL Server

Comment: The first insert is acceptable.  Personally, I'd use -'s and not /'s.   No need to specify the time if there is no time element.  Perhaps this should be a datatype DATE and not DATETIME

Comment: Hi, just looking at the columns in Object Explorer. It says `datetime2(7), null`.. Never seen `datetime2`

Comment: Just a more precise version of datetime  ... did't feel like counting decimals  :)

Comment: If I run an insert for 1st query. Would the time default to `00:00...`?

Comment: Yes it would indeed

Comment: Stick to the ISO formats of `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` when dealing with date and times in SQL Server. They are completely unambiguous, regardless of the data type and language settings. *`yyyy-MM-dd`* is *unambiguous with the new data types, however, not with `(small)datetime`, so I prefer to avoid it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard date format `YYYY-MM-DD` :

```
insert into table1 (date) 
    values ('2020-01-31')
```

Comment: I believe this is the preferred format, where you use dashes to separate the date parts, not the standard one.

Answer (score 1):

For all versions of SQL Server (up until this point in time, SQL Server 2019) the following string format is the "standard" way of inserting string dates into date columns in SQL Server.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (DateColumn) VALUES ('20200131');
```

Where the `20200131` value corresponds to 2020 01 31 (year, month, date without spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Both are acceptable, although the syntax for datetime2 is `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn]`.

```
DATE only   The TIME part defaults to 00:00:00.
TIME only   The DATE part defaults to 1900-1-1.
DATE + TIME Trivial
DATE + TIMEZONE Not allowed.
DATE + TIME + TIMEZONE  The local DATETIME will be used.
```

[Complete list of allowed formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

we can use BOTH

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
           (Date)
       VALUES
           ('2022-03-01')
 GO
```